# Animate does not work properly on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have found this script and would be great but if I scroll to the top all browsers wait around 10 secs to animate back. 
This script animate if you scroll down or up. Down way works fine bet the up way does not.
I do not know what can be the problem. I tried to leave only one animation but the same result.

Thanks

```
$(function () {

  var iScrollPos = 0;
  var header = $('header');
  var li = $('.headerRight nav ul li');
  var logo = $('h2');

  $(window).scroll(function () {
      var iCurScrollPos = $(this).scrollTop();
      if (iCurScrollPos > iScrollPos) {
        header.animate({
          top: '-3.5em'
        }, 250);

        li.animate({
          padding: '0'
        }, 250);

        logo.animate({
          fontSize: '1.5em'
        }, 250);
      }
      else {
        header.animate({
          top: '0em'
        }, 250);

        li.animate({
          padding: '1em'
        }, 250);

        logo.animate({
          fontSize: '2em'
        }, 250);
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: The scroll event fires continously, you probably want to debounce it.

Comment: Do you have a working fiddle or sample we can see? Or at least paste the markup this behaves against?

Comment: I do not have working fiddle. But may it fires continuosly, here is the link where i found it [link]http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2013/07/jquery-detect-scroll-position-up-down.html

Comment: scroll response logic is so annoying to deal with.  checkout some of the jquery plugins for it to make this a little easier on you - http://www.unheap.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably experiencing an effect caused by the animation queue filling up with animate requests. Each animation has to complete on the elements before the next can fire. What you want to do is stop any animations in play when you need to fire off the next.

Without your UI I can't fully tell what you are seeing but I am imagining something like this to resolve. Note the shorthand to stop all at once

```
all = header.add(li).add(logo);
```

and in the conditions:

all.stop(true, false); // stops where it is

Also, I added a class to the items so it only animates if they have not already been animated to the position.

```
    $(function () {

        var iScrollPos = 10;
        var header = $('header');
        var li = $('.headerRight nav ul li');
        var logo = $('h2');

        $(window).scroll(function () {
            var iCurScrollPos = $(this).scrollTop();
            var all = header.add(li).add(logo);
            if (iCurScrollPos > iScrollPos && !all.hasClass('up')) {
                all.stop(true, false);
                header.animate({
                    top: '-3.5em'
                }, 250);

                li.animate({
                    padding: '0'
                }, 250);

                logo.animate({
                    fontSize: '.5em'
                }, 250);
                all.addClass('up');
            }
            else if (iCurScrollPos <= iScrollPos && all.hasClass('up')) {
                all.stop(true, false);
                header.animate({
                    top: '0em'
                }, 250);

                li.animate({
                    padding: '1em'
                }, 250);

                logo.animate({
                    fontSize: '2em'
                }, 250);
                all.removeClass('up');
            }
        });
    });
```

A fiddle of something at least to see it: http://jsfiddle.net/3d4pmvky/